# How can I start initialization of "List of list" with columns

Tags: c#, arrays, list, initialization

I have a list of list and I want to add values column oriented. Like in the following code sample:

```
Data = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
            {
                Data[j][i] = (probabilityList[j]) * K); // It won't work
            }
        }
```

I know it won't work because Data's index does not exist at current situation, and I need to use add() method.

However, I need to add values to list starts with columns:

```
[1   , null] ----> [1, null]
[null, null]       [2, null]
```

How can I add values to a list of list starts with columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create actual lists that you place inside your outer list of lists:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    Data.Add(new List<double>());
}
```

Once you've created all of the inner lists you can go through them and add values to them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
    {
        Data[j].Add((probabilityList[j]) * K);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the number of columns and rows you need you might think about using arrays instead of lists.  When an array is initialized all members of the array are initialized to their default values.  This would make your code

```
double[,] Data = new double[columnCount,rowCount];
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rowCount - 1; j++)
        {
            Data[j,i] = (probabilityList[j]) * K); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A popular way to initialize a list of lists (List<List<T>>) with one line of code is to use LINQ as follows:

```
List<List<double>> Data = Enumerable.Range(0, columnCount).Select(i => new List<double>()).ToList();
```

This will produce a list of empty initialized lists of double type. From here every inner list can be accessed as Data[i] and elements can be added to it as Data[i].Add(double).

Here is a breakdown of what LINQ methods do to initialize a List<List<double> >

1. `Enumerable.Range(0, columnCount)`

Returns IEnumerable collection of Int with the columnCount number of members.

2. `.Select(i => new List<double>())`

For each of the element of the collection returned by the previous step runs a function "new List()" and stores output (initialized empty List of double) in IEnumerable collection (so we get IEnumerable<List<double>> with columnCount number of members).

3. `.ToList();`

Converts the collection in the step above IEnumerable<List<double>> to List<List<double> - the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to `new` up each element of the List of Lists

```
Data = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
  List<double> column = new List<double>();
  for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
  {
    //not really sure if this is the correct code here
    //that would depend on your logic
    column.Add((probabilityList[j]) * K); 
  }
  Data.Add(column);
}
```

A list is not an array. It does not have slots that you just put elements in, it's more like a chain.

So initially you have a `List<List<double>>` that is empty, it has no `List<double>` instances in it. You have to (explicitly) create and add those lists to the `Data` list.

Alternatively, if you do need row and columns with slots for elements, you could use a two-dimensional matrix, like this:

```
var matrixData = new double[rowCount, columnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
  {
    matrixData[j, i] = ((probabilityList[j]) * K); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is not what I asked. This solution add values in row by row. I need to add values column by column (vertically).

Comment: There are neither row not columns in a list of lists. I'll add code about using a matrix which does have rows and columns.

Comment: I want to tried to represent it visually for a better understanding. Thank you for your time I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In short:** You have to **initialize** each collection of `List<T>` inside of your parent `List<T>`  collection.

As you may know, initialization of collections is done throw keyword `new` in .NET Framework.  Otherwise, all inner Lists will be `Null` and you would not be able to access them.

I have applied this concept to your code.

```
var mainData = new List<List<double>>();
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{
  var innerList = new List<double>();
  for (int j = 0; j < rowCount; j++)
  {
    innerList.Add((probabilityList[j]) * K); 
  }
  mainData.Add(innerList);
}
```

Comment: Hi! This is not what I asked. This solution add values in row by row. I need to add values column by column (vertically).

Comment: @UmutCanKöseali Trivial change.  Just initialize all of the inner lists first, and then add items to each of those lists after they're created.